# Risks of "Full" trust mode

Tags: reporting-services, web-config, .net-4.5, code-access-security, full-trust

We are facing [the slow performance issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode) on SSRS 11 and .NET 4.5.

[A solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737758/asp-net-reportviewer-very-slow-in-local-mode) is to set `trust` mode to `full` in `web.config`. What are the risks of such modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can provide a [`Full Trust` level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx) for only assemblies of your need via [`FullTrustAssembliesSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.fulltrustassembliessection.aspx) in web.config, and this can be done only for a [signed assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx):

```
<system.web>
  <securityPolicy>
    <fullTrustAssemblies>
      <add assemblyName="MyCustomAssembly"
        version="1.0.0.0"
        publicKey="a 320 hex character representation
        of the public key blob used with a
        signed assembly"
      />
    </fullTrustAssemblies>
  </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

Note that

> [The default policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tkscy493.aspx) for evaluating permissions grants full trust to the
>   [Global Assembly Cache (`GAC`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx) assemblies and partial trust to the
>   other assemblies.

And also note that you can [configure trust level for an application in IIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772237.aspx).

So this options can help you to determine which exactly assembly should run under `FullTrust` policy, and make other ones to defaults. If, however, you are still being concerning about the trust level for your application or some library, I suggest you to investigate the [Trust Level table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493(v=vs.100).aspx) and answer the questions:

- Does our application work with third-party components?
- Are we running their code in minimal possible trust level?
- What exactly should be able to do custom code in our application?
- Could we manage this permission via [identity for an application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708.aspx)?
- Could we manage this permission via [CAS rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984947.aspx)?
- Could we move the third party code to separate [sandbox ApplicationDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx)?

After that you can manage your application security as you would like. Hope this helps.

See also:
* [ASP.NET Application Security in Hosted Environments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssd9kbbc.aspx)
* [Security Practices: ASP.NET Security Practices at a Glance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998372.aspx#pagpractices0001_codehowtoruninmediumtrust)